# Как правильно составить запрос в БД для отчета?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица со следующей структурой:

| user_id | like | dislike |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |

Требуется составить sql запрос, чтобы увидеть количество поставленных `like` и `dislike` по каждому `user_id`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой конструкцией запроса это можно получить?
Заранее благодарен всем отозвавшимся.

Comment: Что вы пробовали? Что работает, а что нет?

Comment: Конструкция запроса стандартная: `select ... from ... where ...`

Comment: GROUP BY ÷ SUM()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  SUM(like) AS like_count, 
  SUM(dislike) AS dislike_count
FROM some_table
GROUP BY user_id
```